# Cascade ALL don't generated id for children combination

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to insert an object into base via spring data. the object in question contains one-to-many relationships, the problem is when inserting child elements, the identifier of the parent class is not inserted into the records. I can not manually add it by setters. Here is my code:

first entity:

```
@Entity
public class Competition implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_competition")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long identifiant;

    @Column(name = "NOM_COMPETITION")
    private String nomCompetition;

    @Column(name = "COMPOTITION_STATUS")
    private boolean competitionEtat;

    private Integer points;

    private LocalDateTime dateCreation;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Produit> produits;

    Getters setters Constructors ...
```

Second entity :

```
@Entity
public class Produit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long identifiant;
    private String calificationProduit;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "competition")
    private Competition competition;
    private Integer point;
    Getters, Setters, Constructors .....
```

as you can see in the picture the competition id on produit is null.
[image: Produit table screenshot]
Any help !!

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. Here's how you map a bdirectional OneToMany association. Note the mappedBy attribute: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional. Once you have fixed that, you also **must** set the produit's competition. if you don't, then it's null, and since it's null, the corresponding column will be null.

Comment: Thanks for your repaly, i'll take your remak, i have a question, 
when i ask the orm to do a cascade.all, normally it has to insert the identifier in the parent object, i have more than 8 cascades in object competition and i need bidirectional relations

Comment: *normally it has to insert the identifier in the parent object*: no, not at all. That's what **you** would like to happen. Not what the JPA specification says.

Comment: Thank you very much for your anwer, i get the mark :)